# i need to get the data here and the method [ getText() ] not working with me in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

FacilityN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FacilityName);

String FacilityName = FacilityN.getEditableText().getText().toString();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the getEditableText method simply use getText().toString(). Doing so will first return the TextView that the EditText is displaying and then the String of the text